# Need to change String into JSON and return it. The code runs fine except I get the error: java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

Everything seems to be fine except for the `JSON` exception error.

Here it is specifically: `org.json.JSONException`:

```
Value username of type `java.lang.String` cannot be converted to `JSONObject`.
```

There are a number of other `flags` that I can check in `logca`t and everything seems pretty good except that. I think the problem is that I need to convert the String `encodedStr` into a JSON object and return it to `ASYNC TASK`.

```
 private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    //Use HashMap, it works similar to NameValuePair
                    Map<String, String> dataToSend = new HashMap<>();
                    dataToSend.put("username", params[1]);
                    dataToSend.put("password", params[2]);


                    //Server Communication part - it's relatively long but uses standard methods
                    //Encoded String - we will have to encode string by our custom method (Very easy)
                    String encodedStr = getEncodedData(dataToSend);

                    //Will be used if we want to read some data from server
                    BufferedReader reader = null;

                    //Connection Handling
                    try {
                        //Converting address String to URL
                        URL url = new URL(serverUrl);
                        //Opening the connection (Not setting or using CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                        //Post Method
                        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        //To enable inputting values using POST method
                        //(Basically, after this we can write the dataToSend to the body of POST method)
                        con.setDoOutput(true);
                        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                        //Writing dataToSend to outputstreamwriter
                        writer.write(encodedStr);
                        //Sending the data to the server - This much is enough to send data to server
                        //But to read the response of the server, you will have to implement the procedure below
                        writer.flush();

                        //Data Read Procedure - Basically reading the data comming line by line
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //Read till there is something available
                            sb.append(line + "\n");     //Reading and saving line by line - not all at once
                        }
                        line = sb.toString();//Saving complete data received in string, you can do it differently

                        //Just check to the values received in Logcat
                       Log.i("custom_check", "The values received in the store part are as follows:");
                       Log.i("custom_check", line);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                       if (reader != null) {
                           try {
                                reader.close();     //Closing the
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                      }
                  }

                //Same return null, but if you want to return the read string (stored in line)
                    //then change the parameters of AsyncTask and return that type, by converting
                    //the string - to say JSON or user in your case

    **strong text**return encodedStr;**strong text** 
            **strong text**HERE IS THE PROBLEM I BELIEVE. 
                }


                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
                    if (result.equals("") || result == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
                    if (jsonResult == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (jsonResult == 1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("USERNAME", enteredUsername);
                        intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "You have been successfully login");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }


                private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result) {
                    JSONObject resultObject = null;
                    int returnedResult = 0;
                    try {
                        resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                        returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return returnedResult;
                }
            }

            private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
                String rLine = "";
                StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                try {
                    while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        answer.append(rLine);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return answer;
            }

        //************getEncodedData*****************//
            private String getEncodedData(Map<String,String> data) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for(String key : data.keySet()) {
                    String value = null;
                    try {
                        value = URLEncoder.encode(data.get(key), "UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if(sb.length()>0)
                        sb.append("&");

                    sb.append(key + "=" + value);
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }`enter code here`
```

Comment: It seems that your `result` is not a valid JSON. Can you provide it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?